# Reset Column auto-increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, alter-table

I have a table where a certain column has active auto-increment, but I did some tests and during the test I created several records and exclude some of them. I would like to generate new numbers for those who stayed, without having to delete ...
Ex: they were 3 record, one with code 5, the other with 16 and the other with 18. I wanted the first one to be 1, the second 2 and the third 3. Of course the new ones follow the sequence.

Comment: This *almost* sounds like you are actually describing [CREATE SEQUENCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Changing ids is generally a bad idea.  The purpose of an id is to identify rows in a table, both for foreign key relationships and over time.

But you can change the numbers if you need to:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as new_id
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set id = new_id;
```